# How to make a radio button store a boolean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form with the following code to store a boolean. isteacher is a boolean in the db. I'm trying to set this up so that on a sign up form a user would check the radio button for either student or teacher which I would check for in the controller with `if @user.isteacher = true`

```
  <div><%= label :isteacher, "Teacher" %>
  <%= f.radio_button :isteacher, true, :checked => true , :value => true %></div>

  <div><%= label :isteacher, "Student"%>
  <%= f.radio_button :isteacher, false, :value => false %></div>
```

In the schema the boolean looks like this: `t.boolean  "isteacher", default: false, null: false`

**Issue**

When a new user is created and the Teacher radio button is selected, db always reflects student. If I try to edit the registration, the data is saved but each time I return to the form the student radio button is selected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will solve your issue completely but typically you don't want to put :checked => true inside of f.radio_button.  That will ignore the value that has been saved and will just check that checkbox when the page loads.  And you may also want to pass the :value option in the f.label instead as this says that when the label is clicked it should select the appropriate checkbox.  I would suggest trying something like:

```
<div><%= f.label :isteacher, "Teacher", :value => true %>
<%= f.radio_button :isteacher, true %></div>

<div><%= f.label :isteacher, "Student", :value => false %>
<%= f.radio_button :isteacher, false %></div>
```